# Firebase Initialization in Angular2 App

Tags: express, angular, https, firebase

I've created a `FirebaseService` in my Angular2 app as follows:

```
@Injectable()
export class FirebaseService {

    public initialize(): void {    
        var config = {
            apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
            databaseURL: "https://xxxxxxxxxxxx",
            storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        };
        firebase.initializeApp(config);    
    }    
}
```

However when I attempt to call `initialize()` I get the following error in the browser console.

```
VM438:1 Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://xxxxxx" from accessing a frame with origin "http://localhost:3000".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "http". Protocols must match.
```

This suggests that I need to be serving my Angular app from a https server. Given that I'm a newbie and developing and serving my Angular app locally using Express, what is the best way round this?

Do I need to go and learn how to set up https with express, or can I somehow get round this and get back to the https part of my self tuition later?

Comment: You shouldn't need https when serving locally. Are you certain that this was caused by Firebase? Often people get that error when they try to use iframes. If you are sure that the Firebase initialization is the cause, I suggest contacting [Firebase support directly](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) because this is a strange error.

Comment: I've been trying to initialize firebase as a service in the typescript code of my angular app. If I follow the CDN method and initialize in `index.html`, as described [here](https://webcake.co/using-firebase-3-in-angular-2-and-ionic-2/), then I get no such error when starting my app. However, when I try and do the initialization in a typescript service (as shown in my question), I get the stated security error and app stalls when starting.